# These "FICON" NOTAM's contractions aren't in the FAA contraction list. What do they mean?

Tags: faa, notam, runway-contamination

These NOTAMs for KSGF state "Snow" when the icon on the left is hovered over with a mouse.  The contraction "FICON" does  not appear in the [Notam Contractions list](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/systemops/fs/alaskan/alaska/fai/notam/media/cntrns.pdf).

It is currently the middle of June in nearby Oklahoma, and it is hot here, so a NOTAM related to snow doesn't make any sense.

What are these NOTAMs telling us?

[image]

Comment: [FAA JO 7930.107 FICON Reporting](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N_JO_7930.107_Field_Condition_(FICON)_Reporting.pdf)

Comment: @RonBeyer a few appropriate excerpts from that PDF and you've got yourself an answer...

Comment: KSGF is in Missouri. Not that it makes any difference to your question.

Comment: I've wondered that before, why FICON does not appear in the NOTAMs contractions list.

Comment: @TomMcW thanks, I wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FICON is outlined in [FAA JO 7930.107 "FICON REPORTING"](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N_JO_7930.107_Field_Condition_(FICON)_Reporting.pdf).

FICON is the "**FI**eld **CON**ditions reporting. It identifies information that used to be called "braking action", but is now a little more succinct.

The conditions for the runway are reported in thirds, [First Third]/[Middle Third]/[Last Third], with the following data outlined on page 6:

[image]

So 5/5/5 means that the runway is covered with frost or is wet and is "damp or 1/8" or less of standing water". Pilots used to report this as "good" braking action.